# char string* vs char string[]

Tags: c

Is there a difference between:

```
char string = "name";
const char* point = string;
```

vs

```
const char string[] = "name";
```

Will you please explain the difference too?

Comment: Well, for one thing, `char string = "name"` isn't valid C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

The first simply points to a read only section of memory, the declaration really should be:

```
const char* string = "name";
```

The second creates an array long enough to hold the string `"name"` (so, four characters plus one for the null terminator) and copies the string inside the allocated space.